# TensorBoard No scalar data was found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running TensorFlow, I can open TensorBoard in the browser, but it shows the message "no scalar data was found".
When I run `tensorboard --inspect --logdir='training/'` I get a lot of output:

```
======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

   Found event files in:
   training/

These tags are in training/:
audio -
histograms
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_1/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_1/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_2/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_2/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_3/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_3/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_4/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_4/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_5/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_5/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/biases
   ModelVars/BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/weights
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/beta
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/gamma
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/moving_mean
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/moving_variance
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/depthwise_weights
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/pointwise_weights
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/beta
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/weights
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2c_3x3/BatchNorm/beta
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2c_3x3/BatchNorm/moving_mean
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2c_3x3/BatchNorm/moving_variance
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2c_3x3/weights
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/beta
   ModelVars/FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma
...
images -
scalars
   LearningRate/LearningRate/learning_rate
   Loss/HardExampleMiner/NumNegatives
   Loss/HardExampleMiner/NumPositives
   Losses/Loss/classification_loss
   Losses/Loss/localization_loss
   Losses/TotalLoss
   Losses/clone_loss
   Losses/regularization_loss
   TargetAssignment/Loss/TargetAssignment/AvgNumGroundtruthBoxesMatchedPerImage
   TargetAssignment/Loss/TargetAssignment/AvgNumGroundtruthBoxesPerImage
   TargetAssignment/Loss/TargetAssignment/AvgNumIgnoredAnchorsPerImage
   TargetAssignment/Loss/TargetAssignment/AvgNumNegativeAnchorsPerImage
   TargetAssignment/Loss/TargetAssignment/AvgNumPositiveAnchorsPerImage
   batch/fraction_of_150_full
   global_step/sec
   queue/prefetch_queue/fraction_of_5_full
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for training/:
audio -
graph
    first_step           0
    last_step            0
    max_step             0
    min_step             0
    num_steps            1
    outoforder_steps     []
 histograms
   first_step           0
   last_step            2236
   max_step             2236
   min_step             0
   num_steps            69
   outoforder_steps     [(835, 834)]
 images -
 scalars
    first_step           0
    last_step            2237
    max_step             2237
    min_step             0
    num_steps            123
    outoforder_steps     [(835, 834)]
sessionlog:checkpoint
    first_step           1
    last_step            2167
    max_step             2167
    min_step             1
    num_steps            14
    outoforder_steps     []
 sessionlog:start
    outoforder_steps     []
   steps                [0, 834]
 sessionlog:stop -
 tensor -
 ======================================================================
```

This is the train.py:

```
import functools
import json
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import framework as contrib_framework

from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
from object_detection.builders import graph_rewriter_builder
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.legacy import trainer
from object_detection.utils import config_util

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('master', '', 'Name of the TensorFlow master to use.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('task', 0, 'task id')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_clones', 1, 'Number of clones to deploy per worker.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('clone_on_cpu', False,
                     'Force clones to be deployed on CPU.  Note that even if '
                     'set to False (allowing ops to run on gpu), some ops may '
                     'still be run on the CPU if they have no GPU kernel.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('worker_replicas', 1, 'Number of worker+trainer '
                    'replicas.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('ps_tasks', 0,
                     'Number of parameter server tasks. If None, does not use '
                     'a parameter server.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '',
                'Directory to save the checkpoints and training summaries.')

flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', '',
                    'Path to a pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig config '
                    'file. If provided, other configs are ignored')

flags.DEFINE_string('train_config_path', '',
                    'Path to a train_pb2.TrainConfig config file.')
flags.DEFINE_string('input_config_path', '',
                    'Path to an input_reader_pb2.InputReader config file.')
flags.DEFINE_string('model_config_path', '',
                    'Path to a model_pb2.DetectionModel config file.')

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


@contrib_framework.deprecated(None, 'Use object_detection/model_main.py.')
def main(_):
  assert FLAGS.train_dir, '`train_dir` is missing.'
   if FLAGS.task == 0: tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.train_dir)
  if FLAGS.pipeline_config_path:
    configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(
        FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
    if FLAGS.task == 0:
      tf.gfile.Copy(FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
                    os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, 'pipeline.config'),
                    overwrite=True)
  else:
    configs = config_util.get_configs_from_multiple_files(
        model_config_path=FLAGS.model_config_path,
        train_config_path=FLAGS.train_config_path,
        train_input_config_path=FLAGS.input_config_path)
    if FLAGS.task == 0:
      for name, config in [('model.config', FLAGS.model_config_path),
                           ('train.config', FLAGS.train_config_path),
                           ('input.config', FLAGS.input_config_path)]:
        tf.gfile.Copy(config, os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, name),
                      overwrite=True)

   model_config = configs['model']
  train_config = configs['train_config']
  input_config = configs['train_input_config']

  model_fn = functools.partial(
      model_builder.build,
      model_config=model_config,
      is_training=True)

  def get_next(config):
    return dataset_builder.make_initializable_iterator(
        dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next()

  create_input_dict_fn = functools.partial(get_next, input_config)

  env = json.loads(os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG', '{}'))
  cluster_data = env.get('cluster', None)
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster_data) if cluster_data else None
  task_data = env.get('task', None) or {'type': 'master', 'index': 0}
  task_info = type('TaskSpec', (object,), task_data)

  # Parameters for a single worker.
  ps_tasks = 0
   worker_replicas = 1
  worker_job_name = 'lonely_worker'
  task = 0
  is_chief = True
  master = ''

  if cluster_data and 'worker' in cluster_data:
    # Number of total worker replicas include "worker"s and the "master".
    worker_replicas = len(cluster_data['worker']) + 1
  if cluster_data and 'ps' in cluster_data:
    ps_tasks = len(cluster_data['ps'])

  if worker_replicas > 1 and ps_tasks < 1:
    raise ValueError('At least 1 ps task is needed for distributed training.')

  if worker_replicas >= 1 and ps_tasks > 0:
    # Set up distributed training.
    server = tf.train.Server(tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster), protocol='grpc',
                             job_name=task_info.type,
                             task_index=task_info.index)
    if task_info.type == 'ps':
      server.join()
      return

    worker_job_name = '%s/task:%d' % (task_info.type, task_info.index)
    task = task_info.index
    is_chief = (task_info.type == 'master')
    master = server.target

  graph_rewriter_fn = None
  if 'graph_rewriter_config' in configs:
        graph_rewriter_fn = graph_rewriter_builder.build(
        configs['graph_rewriter_config'], is_training=True)

  trainer.train(
      create_input_dict_fn,
      model_fn,
      train_config,
      master,
      task,
      FLAGS.num_clones,
      worker_replicas,
      FLAGS.clone_on_cpu,
      ps_tasks,
      worker_job_name,
      is_chief,
      FLAGS.train_dir,
      graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

What I am missing here?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by supplying full path to`tensorboard --inspect --logdir='/some_path/training/'`instead of relative path (Mac OS X Catalina)

Answer (score 0):

We can upload tensorboard log to the cloud, and in Macbook @mrd 's method works perfectly for me

```
$ pip install -U tensorboard

# For help, run "tensorboard dev --help" or "tensorboard dev COMMAND --help"

# Upload an experiment:
$ tensorboard dev upload --logdir /full/path/logs \
    --name "(optional) My latest experiment" \
    --description "(optional) Simple comparison of several hyperparameters"

***** TensorBoard Uploader *****

This TensorBoard will be visible to everyone. Do not upload sensitive data.

Continue? (yes/NO)

Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth...

Uploading to TensorBoard.dev at https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/QFRIzZJpTZCNRzi8N7zomA
```